# Why do I get a 404 error with Perl's RabbitMQ consumer?

Tags: perl, rabbitmq

RabbitMQ is setup and I can use the sample script:

```
use Net::RabbitMQ;
my $mq = Net::RabbitMQ->new();
$mq->connect("localhost", { user => "guest", password => "guest" });
$mq->channel_open(1);
$mq->publish(1, "queuename", "Hi there!");
$mq->disconnect();
```

It posts messages (I assume).  I tried the following for a simple grab of a message off of the queue and I get a 404:

```
my $mq = Net::RabbitMQ->new();
$mq->connect("localhost", { user => "guest", password => "guest" });
$mq->channel_open(1);
print $mq->get(1, "queuename");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full text of the error message is:

```
basic_get: server channel error 404, message: NOT_FOUND - no queue 'queuename' in vhost '/' ...
```

You need to create the queue with `auto_delete => 0` - otherwise it will go away when the first process terminates. Have a look at the `queue_declare` method.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at `queue_declare` and added it to the listener and changed some code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Net::RabbitMQ;
my $channel = 1;
my $queue = "MyQueue.q";
my $exchange = "MyExchange.x";
my $routing_key = "foobar";
my $mq = Net::RabbitMQ->new();
$mq->connect("localhost", { user => "guest", password => "guest" });
$mq->channel_open($channel);
$mq->exchange_declare( $channel, $exchange, { auto_delete => 0, });
$mq->queue_declare( $channel, $queue, { auto_delete => 0, });
$mq->queue_bind( $channel, $queue, $exchange, $routing_key);

while(1){
    my $hashref = $mq->get($channel, $queue);
    next if (! defined($hashref));
    print Dumper($hashref);
}
```

I kick the listener script off, then, when I execute the following, it posts messages:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $channel = 1;
my $queue = "MyQueue.q";
my $exchange = "MyExchange.x";
my $routing_key = "foobar";
use Net::RabbitMQ;
my $mq = Net::RabbitMQ->new();
$mq->connect("localhost", { user => "guest", password => "guest" });
$mq->channel_open(1);
$mq->publish($channel, $queue, "Message Here");
$mq->disconnect();
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to create an exchange if you're not going to use a routing key when you publish. I would suggest working through [these tutorials](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html). Even thought they are for Python it's easy to translate them to Perl.